# Arrange in graph

Tags: javascript, c#, graph

I have a graph consisting of nodes and edges between them. Can you please advise a library (c# or javascript) to use? It should compute arrangement of particular nodes in order they do not overlap and edges` crossing is minimized.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever checked this page https://www.highcharts.com/demo? I like it very much because you can use the graphs shown there manipulating with javascript, it was so useful for me.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

For JavaScript you can consider http://cytoscape.org/

It is based on HTML5 canvas and it has various layout algorithms that should suffice your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you pick more appropriate tool like Pyhton with plenty of math libraries? C# is not good for such kind of tasks. Neither JavaScript.